# Passing list of different typed elements to a C function

Tags: haskell, tuples, ffi

I have a function written in C I’d like to call from a Haskell program. The function type is:

```
foo :: Int -> Ptr a -> IO ()
```

It takes a size and a pointer on whatever and puts the whole thing somewhere in memory. It’s intended to be used with mixed types. You can put n floats then m bools and so on (in C).

The most convenient way to represent such a situation in Haskell would be – in my opinion – something like `([a],[b])` for instance. But, I need the whole thing to fit in a `Ptr a` (it’s actually a void* in C). I can try to write a function like `([a],[b]) -> Ptr c`, but I need some help around it. The desired final function would be:

```
withArrayLen magicArray foo
```

Comment: Read foreign function interface and how to write storable instance for datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

Things that can be stored in memory are instances of type class `Storable` (in [Foreign.Storable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Foreign-Storable.html#t%3aStorable)). So, given the raw FFI prototype

```
foreign import "foo" c_foo :: CInt -> Ptr a -> IO ()
```

you could write something like this for homogenous lists:

```
homfoo :: Storable a => [a] -> IO ()
homfoo items = withArray items $ \ptr -> c_foo (fromIntegral len) ptr
    where len = length items * sizeOf (head items)
```

But you've said the function is intended to work with mixed types, so we need some kind of type-constrained heterogeneous list for the nice Haskell wrapper. Here is one way to do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data DynStorable where
    MkStorable :: Storable a => a -> DynStorable

foo :: [DynStorable] -> IO ()
foo items =
    let (requiredSize, offsets) = mapAccumL sizeFold 0 items in
    allocaBytes requiredSize $ \ptr -> do
        zipWithM
            (\offset (MkStorable x) -> pokeByteOff ptr offset x)
            offsets items
        c_foo (fromIntegral requiredSize) ptr
    where
    sizeFold offset (MkStorable x) =
        let unalignment = offset `mod` alignment x
            offset' = if unalignment /= 0
                then offset + alignment x - unalignment
                else offset
        in (offset' + sizeOf x, offset')

main :: IO ()
main = do
   foo [MkStorable (2 :: Int), MkStorable (3.0 :: Double), MkStorable True]
```

C function has no means to distinguish item boundaries in the received chunk of data, but it wouldn't be hard to include length prefixes or type codes if required.